# mutate with case_when for the smallest values of the df

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  country = c("CHN","CHN","CHN","LAO","LAO","LAO","GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU"), 
  category = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), 
  value = c(10, 10, 10, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 15, 15, 15, 1, 1, 1), 
  continent = c("Asia","Asia","Asia","Asia","Asia","Asia","Europe","Europe","Europe","Europe","Europe","Europe"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and I am trying to mutate the country column. I would like to keep the country names which have a high value, but if they only account for less than 10% of the total sum of the values of each category, I'd like to group them in continents. The output should be something like this:

```
                    country category value continent
1                       CHN        1  10.0      Asia
2                       CHN        2  15.0      Asia
3                       CHN        3  13.0      Asia
4     Other Asian countries        1   0.9      Asia
5     Other Asian countries        2   1.0      Asia
6     Other Asian countries        3   0.8      Asia
7                       GBR        1  15.0    Europe
8                       GBR        2  17.0    Europe
9                       GBR        3  18.0    Europe
10 Other European countries        1   1.0    Europe
11 Other European countries        2   2.0    Europe
12 Other European countries        3   3.0    Europe
```

But my code replaces the name of *all* countries to "Other asian/european countries". I am not sure where is the problem.

```
df_trial <- df %>%
  group_by(category)%>%
  mutate(
    country = case_when(
      continent == 'Asia' | value<sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)*0.01 ~ 'Other Asian countries',
      continent == 'Europe'| value<sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)*0.01 ~ 'Other European countries'))
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: one thing:  `*0.01` gives you 1% not 10%.

Comment: I think the reason you are getting everything replaced is that you have used or (`|`) not and (`&`).  The first case therefore reads "if the continent is Asia, or if ..." so obviously everything in Asia matches that criterion and gets replaced.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `*0.01` = 10% was a small brainfart, thanks for pointing it out. Regarding the `|` and `&`, it kinda works now if I use `&`, but the name of the countries which don't get replaced by "other countries" gets replaced with an NA. Do you know what I am missing? Or maybe I should replace case_when for ifelse. I tried that before but I also could not make it work...

Comment: See my answer below - your case_when needs a `.default` category for the ones that you don't want to replace.  Also, I think you are comparing each country's value to the total sum, not the per-continent sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to my mind is to slightly reword the "other" category then group by the continent:

```
df |> mutate(country = case_when(value < sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)*0.1 ~ paste0("Other country (", continent, ")"),
             .default = country),
             .by = continent)
```

Gives:

```
                  country category value continent
1                     CHN        1  10.0      Asia
2                     CHN        2  10.0      Asia
3                     CHN        3  10.0      Asia
4    Other country (Asia)        1   0.9      Asia
5    Other country (Asia)        2   0.9      Asia
6    Other country (Asia)        3   0.9      Asia
7                     GBR        1  15.0    Europe
8                     GBR        2  15.0    Europe
9                     GBR        3  15.0    Europe
10 Other country (Europe)        1   1.0    Europe
11 Other country (Europe)        2   1.0    Europe
12 Other country (Europe)        3   1.0    Europe
```

I've left it using `case_when()` in case you prefer to define more specific responses as per your original setup.

Note 10% is 0.1 not 0.01